# Unix find not respecting regex

Tags: regex, linux, unix, find, posix-ere

I'm trying to do a simple `find` in my `/var/log` directory to find all syslog files that are not zipped. What I have so far is the regex:

`syslog(\.[0-9]*)?$`

So this would find `syslog`, `syslog.1`, `syslog.999`, etc and skip over the gzipped logs like `syslog.1.gz` or anything else not matching the pattern of the aforementioned syslogs. I'm doing a pretty basic find command, too:

`find /var/log -regextype posix-extended -regex "syslog(\\.[0-9]*)?$"`

However, I always get an empty result! Now, I thought the regex I wrote was POSIX-extended compatible, but it doesn't seem to be so. Here are variations of the command I ran, to no avail:

`find /var/log -regextype posix-extended -regex "syslog(\\.[0-9]*)?$"`

`sudo find /var/log -regextype posix-extended -regex "syslog(\\.[0-9]*)?$"`

`find /var/log -regextype posix-extended -regex "syslog"`

`find /var/log -regextype posix-extended -regex "(syslog)"`

This following works as expected by listing all files in the directory, however, so I know my command format is correct.

`find /var/log -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex pattern you provide needs to match the *whole* path. That means that you don't need to anchor it at the beginning and end with `^` and `$`, it's already implicitly anchored at both ends. But you *do* need to provide a leading `.*` or something similar if the rest of your pattern should match somewhere other than the beginning (and remember, `find` paths always include a directory, even if it's `.`).

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*syslog(\.[0-9]*)?'
```

works for me.

Comment: Ahhh I didn't know you couldn't do partial matches. Thank you! Accepted.